# Galilean invariance of Burgers Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, chain-rule, fluid-dynamics

Proposition 1.1, Section 1.2 of Majda and Bertozzi reads as follows:

> Let $v,p$ be a solution to the Euler or Navier Stokes Euquations. Then the following tranformations also yield solutions:
> For any $\textbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $v^c = v(x-\mathbf{c}t,t)+\mathbf{c}$ and $p^c = p(x-\mathbf{c}t,t)$

I'm having trouble showing this. As an example I thought to consider one space dimension (instead of 3) the burgers equations: $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$.

For starters, I'm having trouble understanding whether I need to show. Let x' = x - ct and t' = t then either I want to show:

1. $$\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial t} + v(x,t)\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial x} = 0 \implies \frac{\partial v^c(x',t')}{\partial t} + v^c(x',t')\frac{\partial v^c(x',t')}{\partial x} = 0$$

or

2. $$\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial t} + v(x,t)\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial x} = 0 \implies \frac{\partial v^c(x',t')}{\partial t'} + v^c(x',t')\frac{\partial v^c(x',t')}{\partial x'} = 0$$

Either way, I'm getting stuck with the computation. This is related to the question posed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734588/galilean-invariance-of-burgers-equation).

Comment: I think you need to show that $\frac{\partial v^c}{\partial t} + v^c\frac{\partial v^c}{\partial x} = 0$. So your number 1 looks correct to me.

Comment: There's an extra factor of $c$ in the multiplicative term which I can't account for. I think something is bungled in my chain rule, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use a slightly different notation.

Given
$$u_t+uu_\xi=0
$$
for $u(\xi,t)$
show that $U(x,t)=u(x-c t,t)+c$ satisfies
$$
U_t+UU_x=0.
$$
Now it is the chain rule:
$$
U_t=u_\xi (-c)+u_t,\quad U_x=u_\xi, 
$$
whence
$$
U_t+UU_x=u_\xi(-c)+u_t+(u+c)u_\xi=u_t+uu_\xi=0
$$
as required.

Comment: thanks! so this is "Strategy #2" in my question?

Comment: @yoshi No, with your choice of variables and relation between them none of what you have written is correct.